# Margin bottom auto depending on the view height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I make this body margin to bottom if the view height is big like here in the picture?

[image]

For example, if the height of the body goes above the `1000px` how can I margin the body so I wont face that blank space below the footer?

Comment: So the red area overflows and scrolls when the screen is small?

Comment: the red area is the full content i without scroll

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this style on the element that should be fully expanded on the screen:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use view height, `vh`, as the measure in your CSS. E.g.

```
.bigpurplediv {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: 2 correct answers, i wont accept any because it wont be fair :D